# How many times is the function called in this C code?

Tags: c, function, sorting, function-call

This code should show how many times the Sort function is called when we have a range of array starting with l and ending with r. Note that the goal isn't showing the sorted array. So it uses mergesort but I deleted the merge step because the goal is just finding out how many times the Sort function is called.
I don't know which part of the code is wrong and why I can't get the correct answer.

```
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdbool.h>

int counter;
bool isSorted (int array[], int l, int r)
{
    bool flag;
    int i;
    int size=l-r+1;
    if (size==0 || size==1)
        flag=true;
    for (i=l; i<r-1 ; i++)
    {
            if (array[i]<array[i+1])
                flag=true;
            else
                flag=false;

    }
    return flag;
}


    void Sort(int A[], int l, int r) {
    // Sorts [l, r)
    if (!isSorted(A, l, r))
    {
        counter=counter+2;
        int mid = (l + r) / 2;
        Sort(A, l, mid);
        Sort(A, mid, r);
    }
}
int main() 
{ 
    int number,length,c,d,k;
    scanf("%d %d", &length, &number);
    int l[number],r[number];
    int a[length];
    for (c = 0; c < length ; c++)
      scanf("%d", &a[c]);
    for (d = 0; d < number ; d++)
      scanf("%d %d", &l[d], &r[d]);
    void TASort(int A[],int l,int r);
    for(k=0; k<number ; k++)
    {
        counter=1;
        Sort(a,l[k],r[k]);
        printf("%d\n", counter);
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

Two numbers in the first line o input show the number of elements in the array and the number of ranges that the user wants(Using l and r).

For Example:

Input:

```
8 2 
34 7 11 27 2 35 32 16
1 5
3 7
```

Output:

```
5
3
```

Comment: With the specified input, what is the *expected* output? Why do you think the program (as it currently is) is wrong? And have you tried to [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) it? Also please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Fyi,  `counter=counter+2;` yield an incorrect response. If anything you should put `++counter;` as the *first* line in `Sort`. Any recursive invokes will adjust it as expected. As is you're leaving out the initial invoke of `Sort` `number` times.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I wrote the expected output for an example input in the end of question. Yes, I've tried to debug it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at your function `isSorted()`. When there are three or more items of data to look at, there will be two or more comparisons. Each time you set `flag` you don't take into account its current value. This means that the `isSorted()` function will return `true` if the last two items it compared were sorted *irrespective* of whether the previous ones were.